# Postfix & Dovecot - can't receive email - status=bounced (unknown user: "some.name")

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot

I have Postfix and Dovecot running. Postfix is set up to use Dovecot as mail transport. Everything is pretty much by book but every received email is bounced back. I am testing the mail server from gmail.

There are some strange queries for each email:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='receiver@domain' (This is ok)
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='receiver@domain' (This is ok)
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='sender@gmail.com' (Why is postfix checking sender's email against db?)
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='@gmail.com' (Why is postfix checking senders domain against db?)
```

First two mysql queries return a valid result (triple checked).

Bounce message: `Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "receiver.name"`
Only useful bit from maillog: `status=bounced (unknown user: "receiver.name")`

Any troubleshoot ideas or solutions? I have turned verbose debugging both for Postfix and Dovecot but there is nothing more in the logs.

EDIT: 
master.cf - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Yt8QzPfT 
main.cf - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rTdEM9m4

Answer (score 1):

We should clarify first that how Postfix works has nothing to do with Dovecot. They certainly cooperate but do not depend on each other.

It is a very common thing to check the sender/recipient and the sender domain for validity. This is a basic guard against spam and all sorts of other "evil" activity.

While not uncommon, your postfix is configured to check against a DB. This makes it slightly more difficult to troubleshoot. What is your configuration main.cf and master.cf? Without them any guess will be a good possibility.

Comment: True, Postfix is configured to check users against the DB.

Comment: main.cf - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rTdEM9m4
master.cf - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Yt8QzPfT